# Selectively load data into Spark DataFrame

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a usecase where I want to read a subsection of data and then perform some operation on it.

I am doing something like this on spark.

```
DataFrame salesDf = sqlContext.read().format("com.stratio.datasource.mongodb").options(options).load()
```

This seems to load all the data on the table/collection. When I perform a select operation using

```
 salesDf.registerTempTable("sales");
        sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM sales WHERE exit_date IS 08-08-2016").show();
```

It seems like the select operation is being performed on the dataframe that it just loaded. This seems to be a complete waste of space to me.

My table/collection has close to 1 billion records and I want to process just 100,000 of them, loading 1B records in an object seems to be a complete waste of space to me.

Please excuse the naivety of my question. I am very very new to spark. It would be wonderful if someone could provide me a way to just load subsection of table data instead of loading everything and then processing.

Comment: Again I may be naive here but I think that I have not added another piece on the question .. Let me update it ..

Comment: @cricket_007 I make the query on the TempTable "sales" that I create before the query

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense. I would like to believe that the first line simple enables you to query a Mongo collection, not completely loads into memory. However, I'm not familiar with that connector

Comment: This is not a valid SQL, and even if it was, it wouldn't be a correct condition to filter on date.

Comment: @zero323 the query is just made up for illustrative purposes. My question was if I didn't want to load all the data in the mongo collection and just want to load a portion of it and then do processing how would I do that. Currently it looks like the load() function loads everything and then we can query on that dataframe using sql like queries. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: "It seems like the select operation is being performed on the dataframe that it just loaded" Please turn on query logging in MongoDB to prove or disprove that feeling.  The Stratio connector like the MongoDB Spark connector implements the `PrunedFilteredScan` so that it can filter and project out of MongoDB.  Depending on how the partitioner is engineered you may get empty partitions but it shouldn't pass all the data across the wire.

Comment: Perhaps try the official MongoDB connector instead of the Stratio one. I'm not sure if it's any better at query optimisation in practice, but it's something to try.